# Firebird 2.5.2 change blob subtype

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is there a posibility to change the SUBTYPE of a BLOB field ?

I have a BLOB with SUBTYPE BINARY an need to change it to SUBTYPE TEXT, because i get some strange Characters into the BLOB and in a BLOB with SUBTYPE TEXT i don't have this Problem

Comment: What do you mean with 'strange characters'? The binary subtype is for binary data, not for character data.

Comment: ASCII char 255 and 254.
I have another table where the subtype is Text an in this table this chars doesn't exist

Comment: ASCII only goes to 127. What characters do you expect for bytes 255 and 254?

Comment: extended ascii goes to 255
ÿ(255) and þ(254)
but i don't want this chars, somehow they come into the blob after an insert/update

Comment: Extended ASCII is an imprecise name for character sets whose bytes 0-127 are ASCII, and whose bytes 128-255 depend on the character set. Given the characters your mentioning, you either want or use ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 (or a similar character set). The problem you are experiencing might be related to the connection character set (the connection character set might map those bytes to a different character if you request the binary data as a string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Directly altering the subtype of a blob column is not possible (attempts to do this will give the error *"Cannot change datatype for column BLOBCOLUMN.  Changing datatype is not supported for BLOB or ARRAY columns."*)

You will need to

1. Add a new column with an explicit character set (I am assuming windows 1252 based on your comments)

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE table_name
     ADD blobcolumn_new BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT CHARACTER SET WIN1252
   ```
2. Copy the data from the old column to the new column:

   ```sql
   UPDATE table_name SET blobcolumn_new = blobcolumn
   ```
3. Drop the old column

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE table_name
     DROP blobcolumn
   ```
4. Rename the new column

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE table_name
     ALTER COLUMN blobcolumn_new TO blobcolumn
   ```