# Cannot display text data stored in blob sub_type 0 properly

Tags: casting, character-encoding, blob, firebird

There is a field in a table in a database with data type `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0`. It stores text data generally (the field contains 'payment description', so mostly there are values like 'sent successfully', '15$ to go' and so on in that column). I do not know for what purpose that field was designed as `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0`, but the database is provided 'as is' and I cannot affect this.

I need to display the contents of that field as text.

What do I do:

```sql
select 
cast(paym_desc as varchar (1000))
from payments
```

It works, but it works for Latin characters, digits and !@#$%^&*(){}[] signs (those contained in standard ASCII charset I suppose). When it comes to Cyrillic, or Euro signs or pound symbol etc., I get dots instead of symbols.

To troubleshoot the situation I have tried to re-code the column using the solution provided here:
[Firebird 2.5.2 change blob subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818681/firebird-2-5-2-change-blob-subtype)

I've tried creating columns with `blob sub_type 0 character set win1251` and `blob sub_type 0 character set win1251` types and have copied my payment description there.

It is kind of working (no more dots!), but I (as expected) get different values in these columns and none contains what I need. For example, if I set my payment description to

ùúûĀąĈô£¥®҈ѾВАСЯвасяӃ€€€€

I get

Г№ГєГ»ДЂД…Д€ГґВЈВҐВ®Т€СѕР’РђРЎРЇРІР°СЃСЏУѓв‚¬в‚¬в‚¬в‚¬  in win1251 column and
Ã¹ÃºÃ»Ä€Ä…ÄˆÃ´Â£Â¥Â®ÒˆÑ¾Ð’Ð  in win1252 column.

Could somebody please give an advise on how to display such values properly?

Answer (score 3):

A `blob sub_type 0` is a binary blob. Binary blobs don't have a notion of character sets. You need to use `blob sub_type 1` (or `blob sub_type text`) if you want to include a character set.

Based on the conversions you show in your question, it looks like you are storing **UTF-8** into the binary blob, and then retrieve it as WIN1251 or WIN1252.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to create blob sub_type_text column in my table with utf8 charset. I guess if my binary data is actually UTF-8 data it should be displayed properly in UTF-8 encoded column, right? But when I do  UPDATE payments SET paym_desc_utf = paym_desc     I get "Invalid token.
Malformed string.
"     Why could it be?

Comment: That would suggest it isn't UTF8, or it also contains non-UTF8 byte combinations.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any possibility to detect those non-unicode byte combinations and substitute something instead (during cast or before cast) or convert the column from binary blob to text blob?

Comment: @MikhailSergievskiy Firebird is strict when it comes to conversion between character sets, another way would be to load it purely in binary and do the conversion clientside (eg Java replaces invalid byte combinations with a `?`).